# Modern News filter a managed property from taxonomy: contains works, not equal

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, news-webpart

I am using the modern News rollup with a custom property that is correctly indexed. I have noticed that even if the value is a single word, the filter does not work with operator EQUAL and I must use contain. Is this correct?

Edited to add, the term comes from the term store/taxonomy

Comment: Just want to confirm, is the column single selection or multiple selection metadata column?

Comment: single selection

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your scenario but in my case it's working fine. Filter does work with Equal as well

Comment: is the term coming from the term store? or is it a text/choice field?

Comment: it's coming from term store

Comment: could it be because the filter is also "all sites in the hub"? and not just "this site"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unusual that the filter does not work with the operator `EQUAL` for a single-word value in the modern News rollup with a correctly indexed custom property. The operator `EQUAL` should be able to accurately match a single-word value.

There could be several reasons why you are experiencing this issue. Here are a few possibilities:

- **Indexing Issue**: Ensure that the custom property is properly indexed in SharePoint. Check the indexing settings for the property and ensure that it is set to be searchable and queryable.
- **Case Sensitivity**: Check if the operator `EQUAL` is case-sensitive for your custom property. It is possible that the value needs to match the case exactly for the filter to work. Try using the appropriate case when using the operator `EQUAL`.
- **Data Format**: Verify that the single-word value in your custom property is stored in the expected format. There might be additional characters or spaces present in the value that are causing the filter to fail with the operator `EQUAL`.
- **Configuration Issue**: Review the configuration of the modern News rollup and the custom property. Check if there are any other settings or conditions in place that could affect the filtering behavior.

This behavior should be the same for metadata fields in SharePoint. Whether it is a custom property or a metadata field, the operator `EQUAL` should be able to accurately match a single-word value.